# How to zoom a div with css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to a div get bigger when mouseneter

So that´s my code

Script

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".header div").mouseleave(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           height: "50px"
       }, 600);
   });

   $(".header div").mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           height: "100px"
       }, 600);
   });
 })

   menu += "<div class='row ftContainerOut header'><div class='col-md-12 ftContainer header'><div class='row ftHeader'><div class='col-xs-9 t09'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><div class='col-xs-3 text-right'></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6' style='padding-top:10px'><img src='" + items[item].Imagen.Url + "' class='img-responsive img-center' style='border:0px solid blue; max-width:150px;max-height:120px;' /></div><div class='col-xs-6'>" + spec + "</div></div></div></div>";
```

and CSS

```
#header_div {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:#ffffff;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#header_div {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

But nothing occurs when I do mouse enter, any idea why?

The idea is something like these [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LfLaz31m/1/)

Comment: You already have useful part of code, would be much better to have a demo tho

Comment: Zooming is different than resizing. But aside from that, it looks like you are adding the element *after* you are assigning the event handler which means nothing happens. Look into delegating events using jQuery's `on` for example, or ensure that the element is present prior to assigning the event handler.

Comment: I want something like these [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LfLaz31m/1/) @MedetTleukabiluly

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using parts of your code:

Just modify this to your example. Make sure that you're using the same selectors on all the aspects of the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      height: "50px"
    }, 600);
  });

  $(".header").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      height: "100px"
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
</div>
```